# InfoTip on Windows explorer context menu item

Tags: c#, windows, registry, tooltip, contextmenu

I'm creating a `c#` application that adds entries in the registry to add items to the windows context menu like shown in this structure :

- HKCR

  - *

    - shell

      - MyApp

        - command

How can i get a infotip or tooltip while I'm hovering *MyApp* ?
I added a string value `infoTip` under *MyApp* key but it doesn't work.

There's an example : while hovering context menu witch appears when you click on the horizontal arrow from (Start -> Shutdown).

Edit : I used a tool to inspect the class name for that menu and it turns out to be not a `contextmenu` but a `toolbarwindow32` so i suppose that its infotip is not the same as a (`contextmenu #32768`) if there's one.

Answer (score 0):

Likely way too late to help but there's a great library available called SharpShell that will allow you to do this exact thing and many other Windows context menu related functions. It is just terrific. The library is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) and here's [a Code Project page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527058/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Info-Tip-Handlers) where the developer explains how to use SharpShell to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Even if you were/are trying to figure it out for yourself I cannot exaggerate how great of a resource SharpShell source code would be to use as a guide.